# NoClassDefFoundError with AppEngine sample projects

Tags: google-app-engine

I have installed AppEngine Eclipse plugin for Juno according to the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse

However when running a number of the provided sample projects (eg. ShardedCounter), a NoClassDefFoundError would be thrown, stating that class com/google/appengine/tools/development/DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager$StackTraceAnalyzer cannot be found:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager$StackTraceAnalyzer
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.appHasPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:334)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:379)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:408)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:336)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:608)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:541)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$DaemonThreadFactory.newThread(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:644)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addThread(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:721)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:657)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$PrivilegedApiAction.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:270)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$PrivilegedApiAction.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:203)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxy.java:190)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.runQuery(PreparedQueryImpl.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.asIterator(PreparedQueryImpl.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BasePreparedQuery$1.iterator(BasePreparedQuery.java:25)
    at com.google.appengine.demos.shardedcounter.java.v1.ShardedCounter.getCount(ShardedCounter.java:59)
    at com.google.appengine.demos.shardedcounter.java.v1.CounterPage.doGet(CounterPage.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

The only modification I did to the sample projects was to remove the usage of Google Web Toolkit, as the test server could not be started if GWT is used. I have just started trying out AppEngine, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Eclipse to use JDK 7 seem to fix the issue, which explains why it runs on the actual App Engine server but fails locally. Still the error it gives is quite strange...

Probably will do further testing and update the info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add specific jars to your classpath so that they are available during runtime

Comment: Yes I know some jar is missing, but what I need to know is which one is missing, and why is it missing. Is it because of an error in project setup, in runtime config, etc. Notice that it's Google's class that's missing not my own.

Comment: appengine-agent.jar and appengine-agentimpl.jar